# End http request on angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, get

I'm working on an Angular application and I've been having some trouble with my HTTP get. I make a HTTP get every 70 ms but for some reason I always have one or more that goes pending. I would like to know if there is a way I could skip those pending requests or if I could put a timeout?

This is my HTTP get:

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get('http://IP_ADRESS:3490/testStream', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
}

public putData(): void {
   this.canChangePicture = false;
   let comp: number;
   this.getData().subscribe((resp) => {
     console.log(resp);
     const responseArray: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(resp);
     const newTabTemp: Uint8ClampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4);
     comp = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.maxHeight * this.maxWidth * 4; i = i + 4) {
       newTabTemp[i] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 1] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 2] = responseArray[comp];
       newTabTemp[i + 3] = 255;
       comp = comp + 1;
     }
     let nouvData: ImageData;
     nouvData = new ImageData(newTabTemp, this.maxWidth, this.maxHeight);
     this.contextVideo.putImageData(nouvData, BORDERX / 2, BORDERY / 2);
     this.canChangePicture = true;
   });
}
```

Comment: I think you should consider the use of sockets if you send new request every 70ms..

Comment: Consider using web sockets instead of a ping. And that too 70ms is too bad for performance.

Comment: the problem is that I must use a C server and I only found a few C server that were small enough for the space I have. I went with that one: https://github.com/LambdaSchool/C-Web-Server